# Copy Value Of Cell, Not Formula

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to grab only the current number of minutes in an hour.

I use the `NOW()` function and I have the format of the cell it's in set to only `mm`. So in the cell display, if it's 9:08, I get `08`.

Whenever I try a excel formula like `=VALUE(D5)` or `=D5`, I get (I'm assuming this is what it is) an unformatted date string.

I am now looking to macros using VBA to solve my problem.

I've tried:

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(23, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E20").Value`

However I get the same thing as with my excel formulas. Is there any VBA way of getting only the value that's **displayed** in the cell and copied to a new area. It doesn't really need to be copied over, I just need to use the value further in my macro.

I'm open to other ways of getting the current number of minutes in the current hour as well.

Comment: What is the goal? Get the string "08"? Or get the value 8? For the string: There is a =TEXT(Value, "[formatpattern]") function in Excel. `=TEXT(D5,"mm")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do try not to confuse *formatting* and *data*.

why not use `=MINUTE(D5)` in a cell which will set that cell to the minute value *irrespective of formatting*? Use that cell as your source in your VBA.

`=HOUR(D5)` would operate similarly but return the hour part.

Answer (score 0):

If the displays  **9:08**

then select that cell and:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String
    s = Split(ActiveCell.Text, ":")(1)
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Note this is a **String**

Answer (score 0):

Might be calculated like so:

```
=60*(NOW()*24-INT(NOW()*24))
```